# Deploy Web Services on Websphere Portal Server

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

Like we use DeployPortlet.xml file to deploy portlet on webspehre portal server, is there a similar way to deploy web services on webspehere portal server

Answer (score 1):

unless they are WSRP services you cannot using xmlaccess, you would need to use the websphere appserver commands for doing it, either using the automated deployment steps using the properties files and the deployment directory, or using wsadmin to deploy them

Comment: i'm still stuck at it, is there any article which i can refer to do it, because i can't find one.. or can you tell me the steps to deploy web services on websphere portal server.

Comment: are you deploying wsrp? or traditional web services  Look at this article for traditional web services https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_deployapp2.html   xmlaccess for consuming portlets https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYJ99_8.5.0/admin-system/wsrpt_cons_consrv_xml.html xmlaccess on providing wsrp portlets https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYJ99_8.5.0/admin-system/wsrpt_prod_prvd_by_xml.html